Querydsl Q classes are not being generated
I am trying to generate use Querydsl but the Q classes are not being generated even after running mvn clean install. I created a sample application here on Github.
Here is the class:
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    String username;
}

Here is the pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>com.intelidia.intel1</groupId>
      <artifactId>intel1System</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>intel1System</name>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
        <querydsl.version>5.1.0</querydsl.version>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


      </dependencies>
    
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                  <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>11</source>
              <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>com.intelidia.intel1.intel1system/com.intelidia.intel1.intel1system.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                  <launcher>app</launcher>
                  <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                  <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                  <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                  <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                  <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>


The documentation on this is outdated. You shouldn't need the apt.maven-plugin anymore. See this or this bugtracking issue.

On removing this, i am getting this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Entity: jakarta.persistence.Entity

Then you need to add manually the jakarta.persistence-api dependency: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3201#issuecomment-1857452481

works but Q classes are still not generated
